# Find dict matching another dict

Tags: python, json

I have unlimited list of elements(they are rows in document db) containing dicts like:

```
list = [
{a:''}
{a:'', b:''}
{a:'',b:'',c:''}
]
```

And I have input - element, unlimited in count of it's dicts, like:

```
{a:'', c:''}
```

I need a function to find element index matching most dict keys with input.
In this case it would be list[2], because it contains both {a:''} and {c:''}

Could you help me/prompt me how to do it?

Comment: `unlimited list` really ambitious

Comment: Iterate through the list looking for items that match.

Comment: Why cant it be list[3] as it also contains {a:''} and {c:''}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the builtin `max` function and provide a matching key:

```
# The input to search over
l = [{'a':''}, {'a':'', 'b':''}, {'a':'','b':'','c':''}]
# Extract the keys we'd like to search for
t = set({'a': '', 'c': ''}.keys())

# Find the item in l that shares maximum number of keys with the requested item
match = max(l, key=lambda item: len(t & set(item.keys())))
```

To extract the index in one pass:

```
max_index = max(enumerate(l), key=lambda item: len(t & set(item[1].keys())))[0]
```

Comment: That's fantastic

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lst  = [{'a':'a'},{'a':'a','b':'b'},{'a':'a','b':'b','c':'c'}]
>>> seen = {}
>>> [seen.update({key:value}) for dct in lst  for key,value in dict(dct).items() if key not in seen.keys()]

>>> seen
```

**Output**

```
{'a': 'a', 'c': 'c', 'b': 'b'}
```

[check here](https://repl.it/KQ2j/0)